# About implement single HTML page with multiple tabs via CSS with or without JavaScript aid

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, accessibility

I am interested in building a web page with one single HTML file and multiple tabs.

Since only one tab at a time can be selected, I thought that the most appropriate way to handle the user's choice of which tab to show is via radio buttons, i.e. with a `<nav>` wrapping a `<ul>` wrapping a list of `<li>`s each one wrapping an `<input>` followed by a `<label>` (see also [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513776/shoud-i-prefer-navullia-or-other-tag-or-nava-or-other-tag-from-an-a)).

After searching [on the web](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/multiple-tabs-in-single-page-using-javascript-and-css.php) and [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621974/5825294), I've come up with this:

```js
function f(t) {
  // the vector below should be obtainable programmatically from the HTML
  ['tab1', 'tab2'].map(x => document.getElementById(x).style.setProperty('display', 'none'));
  document.getElementById(t).style.setProperty('display', 'initial');
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* With this ruleset I effectively target an HTML element,
   `label`, based on a condition being true or false about
   a different HTML element, `input`. The only relation
   between them is that they are siblings. */
input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}

/* I can't do the same with the element `#tab1` because it
   is not child nor sibling of the one holding the condition,
   the `input` targeted above. So I have to do this */
.tabs {
  display: none;
}
#tab2 {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="site-nav">
    <li>
      <input id="tab1-radio" value="tab1" type="radio" name="nav-tabs" onclick="f(value)">
      <label for="tab1-radio" class="box-shadow">Tab 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="tab2-radio" value="tab2" type="radio" name="nav-tabs" onclick="f(value)" checked="checked">
      <label for="tab2-radio" class="box-shadow">Tab 2</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="tab1" class="tabs">
Tab 1 content
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabs">
Tab 2 content
</div>
```

However I see a few weak (or discussion) points:

- It uses Javascript. Can't the target design really be reached without JavaScript?
- I have to manually match up the `value`s of each `<input>` with the corresponding `id`s of the `<div>` (or `<section>` or whatever tag I use to wrap stuff in).
- I have to manually attach the declaration `display: initial;` to the `id` that is equal to the `value` of the `<input>` that has `checked="checked"`, which is a mouthful to say the least.

---

On the other hand, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211128/multiple-distinct-pages-in-one-html-file) suggests a way to accomplish the task wihtout any JavaScript. I've also found a more thorough guide [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/), but this technique relies on manual `position`ing and handling the stack via `z-index`, but that starts to seem difficult, cumbersom, and that it puts too much burden on the programmer.

Below is my attempt to simplify that approach, but it fails as described in the [linked article](https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/)

> not displaying any tab content if you link to the page without a hash selector, i.e. you link to `mypage.html` rather than `mypage.html#tab1`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.page {
  display: none;
}

.page:target {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="site-nav">
    <li>Click <a href="#one">here</a> for page 1</li>
    <li>Click <a href="#two">here</a> for page 2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

  <div class="page" id="one">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>

  <div class="page" id="two">
Tab 2 content
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do not recommend this for production** and I would instead encourage you to use a proper tabs pattern so you can manipulate the relevant [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/aria/) attributes or a SPA pattern (where you would manage focus after navigation occurs) etc.

But with that being said I did want to show that this is indeed possible (having initial content) using the `:target` selector, provided you don't mind having the DOM order be a little strange (which shouldn't have any accessibility issues as the other sections are hidden).

There is no actual need for the "Home" link I have added, I just put that there for completeness / to give you options.

Also notice something unusual - because of the page change in this manner there isn't always a `<h1>` - I am not actually sure (I will have to think) how to handle this best, but for now I have added a `<h1>` to each section so that every "page" has a `<h1>`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.page{
   display: none;
} 

.page:target {
  display: initial;
}

.page:target ~ .initial  {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="site-nav">
   <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#one">page 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#two">page 2</a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section class="page" id="one" aria-labelledby="section1Heading">
    <h1 id="section1Heading">Tab 1 content</h1>
  </section>

   <section class="page" id="two" aria-labelledby="section2Heading">
    <h1 id="section2Heading">Tab 2 content</h1>
  </section>
  
  <section class="initial" id="home" aria-labelledby="homeHeading">
    <h1 id="homeHeading">Initial Page Content / Home Page</h1>
  </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: Nice trick! Why do you suggest to refrain from using it? Besides, would you mind providing a link to some resources about this _proper tabs pattern_ that you mention?

Comment: https://www.deque.com/blog/a11y-support-series-part-1-aria-tab-panel-accessibility/ did a great write up on Tabs. I wouldn't use the code there (they use jQuery as it is an older post, inline styles etc.) but all of the principles are well explained. The pattern in my answer will work, but the DOM order not matching the order of the "pages" is my biggest issue as if you ever wanted to introduce transitions between tabs it would probably break / result in workarounds, the heading level issue is another strange one I can't decide if it works or not etc. Thanks for tidying my answer by the way!

Comment: (I'm still exploring this topic, as I dont' want to spend time coding without truly understanding the consequence of some choices.) I see that your solution (the one you don't recommend) has the benefit of appending the `href` of the cliked `a` to the URL, so that the chosen tab resists page refreshes. This seems good, but the [page you suggested in the comment](https://www.deque.com/blog/a11y-support-series-part-1-aria-tab-panel-accessibility/) doesn't guide to do anything like that. Am I misunderstanding that solution?

Comment: Just to add to that, I see that the tabs in a GitHub profile page (e.e. [here's mine](https://github.com/Aster89?tab=repositories)) are resistent to refresh, because which tab is selected is encoded in the URL: a trailing `?tab=repositories`, for instance encodes the _Repositories_ tab. And looking at the HTML I see that those tabs are `<a>`s in a `<nav>`, which is a soluiton I'd call inferior to yours which at least puts each `<a>` in a `<li>` of a `<ul>` inside the `<nav>`.

Comment: Finally, I'm having some difficulty in finding resources on this thing of preserving the state of the page (which tab is selected, if a checkbox is selected, how much the user has scrolled down the page, ...) across refreshes. It looks like some of these things (e.g. which tab is selected) are encoded in the URL, as per my previous comment. But I don't even know the terminology of this things, so I'm stuck without knowing what to search :/

Answer (score 2):

I think it could help you.

```css
.content1,
.content2,
.content3 {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #999999;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border-style: solid solid none solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;
}

#tab1:checked+label {
    border-color: #999999;
}

#tab2:checked+label {
    border-color: #999999;
}

#tab3:checked+label {
    border-color: #999999;
}

#tab1:checked~.content1 {
    display: block;
}

#tab2:checked~.content2 {
    display: block;
}

#tab3:checked~.content3 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" checked>
    <label for="tab1">content1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">content2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">content3</label>
    <div class="content1" id="content1">This is first content</div>
    <div class="content2" id="content2">This is second content</div>
    <div class="content3" id="content3">This is third content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this mixes up the tabs and their content in one single generic `div`.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to solve your problem without JS other than this way.

Comment: Because there isn't a CSS selector to select the parent elements yet. [Parent Selector Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

You could write code like this, but it won't work because Selector4 hasn't been introduced yet.

```css
.content1,
.content2,
.content3 {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #999999;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

label {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border-style: solid solid none solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;
}

#tab1:checked+label {
    border-color: #999999;
}

#tab2:checked+label {
    border-color: #999999;
}

#tab3:checked+label {
    border-color: #999999;
}

div:has(#tab1:checked)~div .content1 {
    display: block;
}

div:has(#tab2:checked)~div .content2 {
    display: block;
}

div:has(#tab3:checked)~div .content3 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-container">
        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" checked><label for="tab1">content1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2"><label for="tab2">content2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3"><label for="tab3">content3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content1" id="content1">This is first content</div>
        <div class="content2" id="content2">This is second content</div>
        <div class="content3" id="content3">This is third content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the below HTML snippet, we are using simple input radio buttons fields and labels for every tab title. Then we are adding the content for every tab in a separate div class name `tab__content`. Each input `radio button` has a unique ID, so we can then style it through the CSS.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'cursive';
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.tab-wrap {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s box-shadow ease;
    transition: 0.3s box-shadow ease;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 40px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.tab-wrap:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 12px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.tab {
    display: none;
}

.tab:checked:nth-of-type(1)~.tab__content:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

.tab:checked:nth-of-type(2)~.tab__content:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

.tab:checked:nth-of-type(3)~.tab__content:nth-of-type(3) {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

.tab:checked:nth-of-type(4)~.tab__content:nth-of-type(4) {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

.tab:checked:nth-of-type(5)~.tab__content:nth-of-type(5) {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
    transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

.tab:first-of-type:not(:last-of-type)+label {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.tab:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)+label {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.tab:last-of-type:not(:first-of-type)+label {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.tab:checked+label {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #fff inset;
    cursor: default;
}

.tab:checked+label:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #fff inset;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.tab+label {
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #eee inset;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-box-flex: 3;
    -ms-flex-positive: 3;
    flex-grow: 3;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s background-color ease, 0.3s box-shadow ease;
    transition: 0.3s background-color ease, 0.3s box-shadow ease;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
}

.tab+label:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f4f4f4 inset;
}

.tab__content {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-wrap">
   <!-- active tab on page load gets checked attribute -->
   <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabGroup1" class="tab" checked>
   <label for="tab1">Short</label>
   <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabGroup1" class="tab">
   <label for="tab2">Medium</label>
   <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabGroup1" class="tab">
   <label for="tab3">Long</label>
   <div class="tab__content">
      <h3>Short Section</h3>
      <p>Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab__content">
      <h3>Medium Section</h3>
      <p>Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
      <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Pellentesque posuere. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab__content">
      <h3>Long Section</h3>
      <p>Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
      <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Pellentesque posuere. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra.</p>
      <p>Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
      <p>In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Pellentesque posuere. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```